# Laravel Route, ->name method?

Tags: laravel, routes, definition

Laravel 5.5
which is the different doing (no get and post methods) on route defintion web.php file:

```
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

regarding `->name('')` method

Is required define that method? in which cases?

(sample taked from Auth Class definition laravel)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea of defining `->name()` in routes is for easier code maintenance in the future, it's not mandatory.

Say for example you have few places which uses the route `login`, one fine day you update the route to `user-login`. You will have to find and update all the route being used, changing from `url('login')` to `url('user-login')`.

If you have a route name defined, you will be using `route('login')`, when you update your route url, there's no need to update all the other files that you're using that route.

Comment: @user3186511 welcome, please upvote and accept the answer if it helps you :)